# Is there a breadboard for DDR4 card slots?

Tags: breadboard, ddr4

I've got a TE 2309413-1 card slot on my project board and I'm looking for a development board that I can use and plug into the slot. Does anyone know if such a thing exists? My Google-fu isn't turning up any results...

Answer (score 2):

I hope you're not referring to actual DDR4, as even the lower ends of speeds that you could opeate them on (and still do something useful in between refreshes) would be very hard to achieve for a breadboard design.

If this is just about the connector commonly used for DDR4 RAM, but not actually about DDR4: these are 288 pin DIMMs. So, assuming you even split these out to two DIL rows, each side of your breadboard adapter would have to have 144 pins. On 2.54mm pitch (as usual for breadboard), that would make it roughly 36 cm long.

So, no, it's very unlikely this would exist.

However, it would be fairly easy to design an adapter board yourself, if you only cared about a few of the lines; since that sounds like a very application-specific problem, you'd have to do that design yourself. If you are happy with not having gold-plated contacts, such a small board would be very cheap to get from the usual mini-run board houses (oshpark, aisler, jlcpcb,...)